# How to create jenkins library locally without the folder structure mentioned in the manual

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The problem:
I have couple "JenkinsFile" files in the project which are both sharing the same bundle of steps in their pipelines.
I thought that it would be nice to just bundle those steps together in some complementary file, save this in the same repository and reference it like some javascript module or a defined macro.

As I started digging into tutorials, I have found a solution in the form of a library. But to use it I need to take a gargantuan number of steps to make such a simple change:

1. Make a repository
2. Make a folder structure
3. Make some changes in Jenkins UI (which I don't want to do because it complicates the job maintenance)
4. Make some over-complicated calls to get access to those lines of code you saved

This all seems like too much redundant work to save some code which is only used in couple places of a single project.

Maybe I am just researching the wrong thing and there is an easier solution? Could someone please give a pointer to an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkinsfiles are all in the same repo, you could create a `.groovy` file which has the common code and import that file to all the Jenkinsfiles that you need without creating a shared library.

If you have Jenkinfiles spread across many repos, then a shared library is your best option. You need to have a block of code that is accessible by multiple pipelines, so you obviously need to store it in someplace that is commonly accessible by all the pipelines, like a separate repo. You also need to ensure that Jenkins can access this repo, which why you need to configure this in the Jenkins UI, as the shared library is checked out immediately upon the pipeline starting. To refer to this shared library, all you have to do is to import the library and call the function, which is generally how libraries work and is not really that complicated.